# TFS: How to find untracked files in a TFS workspace?

Tags: tfs

Is there any easy way to list all untracked files in a TFS workspace, like what "git status" reports in the "untracked files" section, or the output of the following command:

```
git ls-files --other --exclude-standard
```

Answer (score 9):

[TFS PowerTools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/site/search?query=%22power%20tools%22&f[0].Value=TFS%20Power%20Tools%20Team&f[0].Type=User&f[1].Value=%22power%20tools%22&f[1].Type=SearchText) works for me! I also find I can get the same result with the following command:

```
tfpt treeclean /noprompt /preview /recursive
```

Comment: This did not work for me.  It told me there was nothing to delete.  Do I have to do that *before* an Undo?  My problem is I unshelve something, then undo which does not delete the added files.  The next time I unshelve, TFS conflicts with files still on the hard drive.

Comment: @Sebastien Make sure you select all the files in the undo pending changes window or that you invoke undo changes from the TFS Source Control window, instead of from the solution explorer.

Comment: @jessehouwing I almost always work from the source code explorer and new files have never been deleted on an undo in my experience.  They always remain on the filesystem even if they are removed from the solution.

Answer (score 3):

TFS PowerTools can do that

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/tfs2008/bb980963.aspx

After installing it, from the command line try:

tfpt online

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio IDE, in Source Control Explorer, right click on a folder an choose "Compare". This will allow you to compare local folder with your source control folder. There are various options there as well like ability to show or hide items that exist only on one side, exclude files by extensions, etc